# Proper signature for VSTO's Button.GetImage

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon-control

I have created a working add-in for Outlook and now I try to add an image to a button. I've seen in many questions that you need to set the `getImage="GetImage"` property and provide a callback function for it, so I did:

```
public Bitmap GetImage(IRibbonControl ribbon)
```

However, with this method the add-in doesn't even load. I tried a couple of other signatures like

> ```
> public stdole.IPictureDisp GetImage(Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl ribbon)
> public Bitmap GetImage(Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl control)
> public stdole.IPictureDisp GetImage(string idMso, int Width, int Height)
> ```

but none of them worked. What is the correct signature of this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it and I post a self-answer, maybe it helps someone someday...

In order to use the `getImage` callback you **must not set** the `image` property. It's either or.

Answer (score 1):

The `getImage` callback's signature is listed below:

```
C#: IPictureDisp GetImage(IRibbonControl control)
-
VBA: Sub GetImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef image)
-
C++: HRESULT GetImage([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] IPictureDisp ** ppdispImage)
-
Visual Basic: Function GetImage(control as IRibbonControl) as IPictureDisp
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: These links contain tons of interesting information! Thanks! :]